# Not getting forward for the page in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, firefox

I am developing a simple log in form by using `XML file` values. I have an XML with values `last name` and `first name`. I am accessing the file and checking the values against the given values in order to validate log in. 
It works fine in chrome, IE and safari. But, In mozilla it is not getting forwarded to the next page. The page just stays in the same page and shows a loading URL icon for indefinite time.

Here is my CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    
  <link href="css/stylemp3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 </head>
 <body>

 <form onsubmit="return myFunction()" action="action.html">
  First name:<br/>
  <input type="text" required="required" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>
   <br>
   Last name:<br>
   <input type="password" required="required" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>
   <br/>
   <select class="dropdown" id="ddl">
    <option value="haha" selected="selected">show</option>
    <option value="hihi" >hide</option>  
   </select>
   <br/>
   <input type="text" name="hide" id="hidee" class="hide"/>
   <br/>
  <input button type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form> 
 <div></div>
 <script>
 window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("firstname").focus();
};
$( "#ddl" )
  .change(function () {
    if($( "select option:selected" ).text() == "hide")
 {
 $("#hidee").hide();
 }   
else
{
$("#hidee").show();
} 
  })
  .change();
  </script>
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
var lastname = document.getElementsByName('lastname')[0].value;
var firstname = document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","login.xml",false);
 
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("login");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
 {
  alert(x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  if((x[i].getElementsByTagName("firstname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == firstname)
  {
   alert("Smileeee.....:-))");
   if((x[i].getElementsByTagName("lastname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) == lastname)
   {
    alert("login Successful!!!!!");
    return true;
    break;
   }  
  }
 
 }
 return false;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in your server script? Firefox doesn't allow your `XMLHttpRequest` to access cross domains to fetch data.

Comment: No. How to add it in the code?

Comment: Find more details on the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin